# How to unit test a python script accepting arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following python script which can be imported into a module or can be run standalone

```
# MyScrpt.py
import argparse

def DoSomething(s: str):
    return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Learning to unit test python')
    parser.add_argument('-myarg1', type=str, dest='myarg1', required=True, help='Help yourself')
    parser.add_argument("-myarg2", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("-myarg3", action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    value = ''
    value = DoSomething(args.myarg1)
    print(value)

    if args.myarg2 == True:
        value = DoSomething('Something')
    
    print(value)

    if args.myarg3 == True:
        value = DoSomething('SomethingMore')
    
    print(value)
```

`DoSomething` is a method I want to unit test. It should return exactly the string passed into it.

**Question:**
How can I unit test this script? Should I simply write a script to call `DoSomething` and assert return value? Since it is accepting arguments, is there something more extensive in python to unit test a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the command-line entrypoint in a function that optionally accepts `argv` (as `ArgumentParser.parse_args()` does).

```
import argparse


def DoSomething(s: str):
    return s


def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Learning to unit test python")
    parser.add_argument("-myarg1", type=str, dest="myarg1", required=True, help="Help yourself")
    parser.add_argument("-myarg2", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-myarg3", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    value = ""
    value = DoSomething(args.myarg1)
    print(value)

    if args.myarg2 == True:
        value = DoSomething("Something")

    print(value)

    if args.myarg3 == True:
        value = DoSomething("SomethingMore")

    print(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you can test the main function, passing it args as you like. The below script would likely run as-is with the [Py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/) test runner.

```
import io
import contextlib
from myscript import main

def test_main():
    stdout = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(stdout):
        main(["foo", "-myarg1", "baz", "-myarg2"])
    assert stdout.getvalue() == "... something..."
```

Comment: `test_main` can call the main by arguments. Thats what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: In `test_main`, is `foo` the name of the python script being tested? I gave a name to the script in my question now. May be you could improve your answer if you like

Comment: It doesn't matter, hence the metasyntactical placeholder `foo`. `sys.argv` (which is what `argparse` would ordinarily read) contains the script name as the first item, but `argparse` only really uses it for formatting help.